# How to create a rounded bevelled cylinder? Without meshes becoming messy? And a smoothly flat plateau on top?

Tags: mesh, objects, bevel

I have cylinders and I would like them to have a rounded beveled effect with a flat plateau on top. Sort of like this button effect:

[image]

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I see someone online suggested using control B and posted this demo:

[image]

But I notice in that demo, the mesh is nice and simple with no crossing lines and it created a smooth concentric effect.

If I grab the top surface, and I try to bevel with control B I get this, which is good, but I can't clearly get the smoothing:

[image]

I need the top surface to be ABSOLUTELY FLAT with smooth rendering on - not bubbling all the way to the midpoint.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Either use Chris' method with the bevel modifier, or use your method and roll the mouse wheel forward while bevelling to increase the number of segments then right-click and Shade Smooth in Object mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a cylinder

[image]

2. turn on autosmooth

[image]

3. add bevel modifier with these settings

[image]